# Import SQLLite File on PHP Server

Tags: php, android, sqlite, pdo, import

I exported a Database from my Android Application to my PHP server. The fact is that I haven't got a way to deal with SQLite.

That's strange because the file has no extension ...

So how can I import my SQLfile on my PHP server to import the database and test it on my server ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How to move SQLite databases: Step 1. Copy. Step 2. Paste.

Comment: But the fact is that I've got only PhmyAdmin, and the format of the file is very strange... So I don't see how it's going to work :/ I've got only PhpMyAdmin on my hosting ... And I can not install anything else...

Comment: SQLite databases are 1 file only. PhpMyAdmin is for MySQL (or compatible), if you want to use the database in your server, copy it using @Sammitch and then just create a [PDO connection to it](sqlite:/opt/databases/mydb.sq3).

Comment: What's @Sammitch ? I never heard about this :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the sqlite file with the [Firefox SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) extension and use that to export the table as a .sql or .csv file